# Is the font difference of 'history' of the answers of a nominated user for the election different from 'link' and 'flag' intentional?

Tags: bug, status-review, election

Maybe the impact of this is not significant, but here is the image (I used MS Edge, 200% for the image):

[image]

I inspected the elements, and both `link` and `flag` use `-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Liberation Sans",sans-serif` as fonts. For `history`, the font used is `Arial`.

I want to ask if this is intentional or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have [raised this on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371773/election-questionnaire-history-is-titled-revisions-to-unknown) and it is currently under status-review. The three bugs are:

- "Revisions to unknown" page title for questionnaire revision history page
- "history" button has different font (size)
- "return to original post" link missing from both intro and questionnaire revision history pages

which will all be added to the bug report.

The particular "history" font issue has in fact been raised weeks ago; [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368457/the-history-link-under-nominations-on-election-pages-is-dislocated-and-larger), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370880/history-button-is-not-aligned-with-the-other-links-on-the-election-page) (thanks to @TheAmplitwist for finding these) so I would imagine it will be sorted soon.